# How to use two different web api services for migration of database using each other's services?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

How I can use the webapi services in mvc4 for fetching the data from one database and insert that data in another database. I am using one web api project for fetching the data and trying to insert or perform operation in another web api project which is dealing with another database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
string json = client.DownloadString("URL");
JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
dynamic item = serializer.Deserialize<object>(json);
```

> Hi Alpesh, I'm sure this one will help you.

Comment: thnks i am trying this now